# Magento order emails not sending

Tags: magento, email

When people place an order on my online store I am not receiving a notification email. The customer isn't receiving order emails either.

I am able to send emails to customers (their order details, password updates, etc.) manually, but we're not receiving any order notifications automatically.

Under Sales Emails, I have my email address (same domain as store url), and copy method separate email. I've done this for all sales emails. All other sending options are default (disable email communications: no, host: localhost, port: 25, set return path: no).

If anyone has any suggestions I'd love to hear them :)
Thanks in advance,
Bob

Answer (score 1):

1.

> Mail Sending Settings:
>
> host: localhost

host may vary from one server to other server sometimes, check whether your host is localhost or any other. My server is not using localhost.

2.
Compilation may be enabled in your server. So your settings will not be affected untill you run the compilation after made any changes in your server. You may check the mail issues after disable compilation.

3.
If all fine and mail still not working, then you can try this free extension [CheetahSender](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cheetahsender-3643.html).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check with php mail at your server i am sure that your server mail is disabled or somehow its not working.. so check it by simple **mail** function of php at root directory and then after check with magento..

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not install the sendmail in your server. Type:

`sudo apt-get install sendmail`

Answer (score 0):

If all other emails are working then check with cron job. in magento 1.9 its based on cron job. so you can trace through..